# Trouble with jquery loading json

Tags: jquery, json

Hi Can anyone help me with loading json into jquery I can only seem to get it to work in this structor

{
"name": "Zemi All",
"smpx" : "2564",
"scuser": "zajihi",
"scfollowers": "female"
}

This is the format page I have - http://newmusicproducer.com/filterable/indexj.php

My code below is:

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#driver").click(function(event){
          $.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {
            $.each(data.results,function(){
              $('#stage').html('<p> Name: ' + data.name + '</p>');
              $('#stage').append('<p> Smpx : ' + data.smpx+ '</p>');
              $('#stage').append('<p> Scuser: ' + data.scuser+ '</p>');
              $('#stage').append('<p> Scfollowers: ' + data.scfollowers+ '</p>');
            });
          });
      });
   });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <p>Click on the button to load results:</p>
   <div id="stage" style="background-color:blue;">
          Display area.
   </div>
   <input type="button" id="driver" value="Load Data" />
</body>
```

Comment: What error do you get? Is the file on your server? Are you really loading `test.json` or are you trying to access the site above?

Comment: no the link is the format I am trying to load its same site. no error just not getting any data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over `data.results` but the link you provided shows that the array is called `testData`.

```
$.each(data.testData, function(val){
    $('#stage').html('<p> Name: ' + val.name + '</p>')
               .append('<p> Smpx : ' + val.smpx+ '</p>')
               .append('<p> Scuser: ' + val.scuser+ '</p>')
               .append('<p> Scfollowers: ' + val.scfollowers+ '</p>');
});
```

Comment: OK I changed the code to that and now it does pull data but just says undefined.

Comment: Just worked it out with your advice and also had to change the 
 $('#stage').html('<p> Name: ' + data.name + '</p>');
to
 $('#stage').html('<p> Name: ' + val.name + '</p>');

Comment: Oops, missed that.  Updated the answer for future readers' benefit.  Also as a note, you can use chaining instead of reselecting the `#stage` element every single time.

Comment: Thanks for updating the post! , Chaining just noticed your post nice quick type thanks.